# Doing the same tasks from multiple places when using Clean Architecture and CQS?

Tags: design, clean-architecture, cqs

I'm working on some tooling that will help speed up the process of setting up a new computer for new developers. I want the user to be able to execute many tasks either as one task or grouped together with other tasks. For example, setting up the server might consist of the tasks `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Let's say that `A` is installing IIS as an optional windows feature and `D` is adding our Web Applications to an IIS site. I want the user to be able to perform `D` individually as well, we might add or remove an application and then we don't want to force the user to go through `A-C` just to do `D`.

The tool is built using Clean Architecture. If we invoke the tool with

```
> my-tool D
```

the presentation layer will simply invoke `DCommandHandler` by passing `DCommand` to a mediator. `DCommandHandler` contains the code to perform task `D`.

Now to my problem, how do I orchestrate invoking task `A-D`?

```
> my-tool setup-everything
```

My first thought where to let `CompositeCommandHandler` do the work:

```
Handle()
{
    _mediator.Send(new ACommand);
    _mediator.Send(new BCommand);
    _mediator.Send(new CCommand);
    _mediator.Send(new DCommand);
}
```

This feels ok-ish for this use case but generally I don't like the idea of invoking other handlers from a handler. I could move the code from `CompositeCommandHandler` to the presentation layer but the tasks *must* be invoked in order so I really think Application should own that logic.

I could move the logic for performing `Task X` into a separate class that can be invoked from multiple places:

```
ACommandHandler:
Handle()
{
    _taskA.Execute();
}

CompositeCommandHandler:
Handle()
{
    _taskA.Execute();
    _taskB.Execute();
    _taskC.Execute();
    _taskD.Execute();
}
```

However now all handlers will just invoke `Task X` and that starts to smell like lasagna code... I need task `A-D` to be invoked in the correct order so I can't use events/notifications either. I'm not sure what would be the best way to solve this problem, any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do `new TaskA().Execute()` instead of just `DoTaskA()`?

Comment: It's just dummy code but yes, it should be its own class so that it can be injected in both `ACommandHandler` and `CompositeCommandHandler`. If the code didn't need to be reused, I would just put it in `Handle`.

Comment: I tried to abstract away the implementation details but sadly my skills in UML is non-existing :( If anyone wonders, I'm using NET 5 to build a console application and I'm always using DI.

Comment: What piece of code is responsible for translating the command line argument into the invocation of a handler?

Comment: The presentation layer parsers the args.

Comment: I tried to avoid all implementation details since this isn't SO but that seems to be very interesting.. There is actually two presentation layers, there is a cli and a gui.